# JS: jQuery selector problematic, dont have a clue

Tags: jquery, html, object, selector, inheritance

I question how to select a specific object by jQuery.
Following situation:

```
<figure class="box col1">
    <img class="fade" src="first.jpg" style="background-image: url(second.jpg)" />
    <figcaption>
      <div class="cenfig">
         <p>
          <strong>Headline</strong>
          <em>Subheadline</em>
        </p>
    </div>
</figcaption>
```

There are several figures in a document. I want to select the img inside the figure and run a script on it.

The Question:

Is it possible to use a mouseover on the figure to run a function only on the img inside that mouseovered figure?

Check this to understand my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/NuL7A/1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
  $("figure img.fade").mouseover(function(){
    //...
    });
```

Comment: Mh. No. It cant select the img.fade because it is several z-index layers behind the figcaption.